# Puppet Not Loading Custom Facts

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet and trying to write a basic manifest to start learning the ins and out.

I am trying to insert a custom fact into my manifest, and write it into a file. The custom fact I created shows up in the list when I issue the `facter` command, but it doesnt not show up when I apply the manifest. I am just trying to run this locally, I do not have a puppetmaster set up.

Can anyone help and shed some light on what I may be missing?

I create the fact like:

```
export FACTER_TEST=helloworld
```

My manifest looks like this:

```
file {'/tmp/test1':
ensure  => present,
content => "testing - $test - $puppetversion - hello",
}
```

I apply the manifest like:

```
sudo puppet apply testmanifest.pp
```

The result is that the fact just shows up as blank in the newly created file.

The file looks like:

```
testing - - 3.7.2 - hello
```

My puppet.conf looks like:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=/var/lib/puppet/lib/facter
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN 
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
```